# PowerShell Remote Access Configuration

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

Trying to configure remote PowerShell access on a server but cannot avoid access denied errors.

What I have done:

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration 
  -Name EngrStudentAdmin 
  -RunAsCredential domain\delegatedAdmin 
  -StartupScript 'C:\Scripts\Students\Welcome.ps1' 
  -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI
```

(on a single line - displaying above for readability)

Using the permissions GUI, I granted the group DelegatedAdmins Read and Execute permissions.  The startup script is just filler.

```
$welcome = 'Welcome to ' + $env:COMPUTERNAME
Write-Host $welcome
```

Attempting to connect to the endpoint with

```
Invoke-Command 
  -ComputerName $server 
  -ConfigurationName EngrStudentAdmin 
  -ScriptBlock { hostname }
```

fails with the error

```
AuthorizationManager check failed.
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (engr-mgr1.domain.edu:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionStateBroken
```

- The execution policy on the server is RemoteSigned and the startup script is signed.
- The account used to access the server is a member of the DelegatedAdmins group.
- Opening a local shell as delegatedAdmin shows that the account has permission to run the startup script.
- Using a member of the local admins group, the Invoke-Command, without the ConfiguationName switch (i.e. connecting to the default endpoint), executes so the winrm service is running and PSRemoting enabled.
- The delegatedAdmin account has no profile.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Check that the WMI service is enabled and running, if it's disabled try starting it and then retrying.

Also check the properties of the actual file, it might have been blocked.

Answer (score 0):

are both Domain joined? If not you might take several further steps.
In general: Try this on the remote system: `Enable-PSRemoting -Force -Verbose` If you see nothing, it was already applied. If not, this will make alle necessary changes for you.

Just in case: Check your Firewall settings :-)

As Dewi mentioned: Check the WMI Service.
Here is a quick hack to enable it (if you want to enforce it):

```
# Configure WMI
Set-Item -Path wsman:\localhost\client\trustedhosts -Value * -Force -Confirm:$False
# Restart
Restart-Service -Name WinRM -Force
```

Last but not least: Use the `-verbose` switch to see more details.

Like this:

```
New-PSSession -ComputerName $ComputerName -Credential $credencial -Verbose
```

Cheers
Josh